# Enable XSLT with Webmin on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, php5, webmin, xslt

I am trying to install/enable XSLT for PHP on my webserver. I'm quite sure that it was running before I made an update, but now it does not work anymore.

I have an Ubuntu webserver with Webmin installed, so how can I find out if the required module is present and how can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install XSLT use following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

To see installed modules use:

```
php -m
```

To see if XSLT is installed use:

```
php -m | grep xsl
```